# Configuration vs Scopes/Stores

Tags: configuration, store-view, core-config-data, scope

I work on `Magento 2.1`.

I have one website, store and store view. I understand that if in future client needs to add another language to store he will add just a store view. Am I correct?

Now, I have to save some values in `core_config_data`. What is the best way to save them, to not disturb adding stores/store views/websites in future (especially store view is interesting for me) in future?

Now when I track saving values in adminhtml - they are saved in `Default config` and in db in column `scope` they get `default` and in column `scope_id` they get `0`. Is this correct policy to leave it like that?

I use method `saveConfig` from `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface`,

***like this:***

`$this->config->saveConfig('path/to/field', 1, ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $this->provideAdminStoreId());`

Is that correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you current way is best to adding the values for core config.

```
$this->config->saveConfig('path/to/field', 1, ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $this->provideAdminStoreId());
```

**yes it is correct way leave it like that.**

it all depend on how you retrieve data. You have to add scope check in retrieving data.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'path/to/field',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
```